# AOA Diagram Help!

Tags: work-breakdown-structure

So I am trying to create an [Activity on an Arrow diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_diagramming_method) for the below table and I am having trouble grasping the whole concept I am currently in Visio trying to do it myself any input or help would be appreciated!

[image: Requirements]

Comment: What do you mean when you say "AoA"?  Can you expand the acronym?

Comment: Arrow on Arrow diagram.

Comment: In my experience AoA always refers to Analysis of Alternatives; I've updated the question to clarify the ambiguity.

Comment: I made a small edit. This type of diagramming is often called Arrow Diagramming Method (ADM) (as per the link). I've always used it as Activity on Arrow method. The core concept is that the end points are start/end points and the activity is executed over the intervening period. This method is good for working out critical paths and potential schedule crashing.

Comment: Just a note since the editor wants more than minor edits. The prevailing nomenclature for the method is Activity on Arrow. The change made on the 23rd made this less correct.

Comment: If you start with a dummy time node of 0, then a second node at 2 with "A" on the arrow in between, does that help conceptualize how the flow might start for you? 0 --- "A" ----> 2 --- "C" ---> 4 also from time node 2 --- "B" ---> 5.

Answer (score 1):

[image]This is the activity on Arrow diagram for the above WBS

Answer (score 0):

For an AoA diagram, the arrow itself represents the activity.  Create a node--a small black circle--and draw an arrow moving from left to right.  On top of this arrow, insert the letter A - 2 weeks and end the arrow with an arrow tip that touches your next black circle.  Do the same thing from this second black circle and draw an arrow moving from left to right.  On top of this arrow, insert the letter B - 5 weeks and end this arrow with an arrow tip.  The fact that the first arrow, A, is touching the node that begins the arrow, B, creates the dependency.  You would interpret this that B cannot start until A finishes and it will take A two weeks to finish.

Simply repeat the above process as you move from C to L.

[image]

Now, I put letters in the node itself, which is not technically correct.  The arrow itself is the work; the node signifies start and stop.

Comment: Having trouble grasping it could you post an example of what you said other than that extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

According to [Arrow diagramming method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_diagramming_method) and your source information:

[image]

AoA Diagram:

[image]